# Node Js Express session on Amazon Ec2 server

Tags: node.js, session, express, amazon-ec2

I have my node.js website hosted on an Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2012 instance and some time after I start my node.js server, the Express session seems to not work anymore and I need to restart my node.js server.

It seems that my node.js server is "sleeping" after some time.

In my app.configure i have the code:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret: 'xxx', cookie:{maxAge : new Date(Date.now() + 3600000)} }));
```

Someone knows something about this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code ? What is the node.js server doing ?

Comment: You may be limited by the default session store. Cookie age only controls the point at which the cookie will expire, not when the session will be cleaned up on server side.